# Js код помогите

Tags: javascript

Есть такой код, по другому его не назвать. Нужно чтобы Padding-top объекта равнялся половине высоту другого объекта, пытаюсь делать так ничего не получается:

```js
var oBlock = document.getElementById('sub_bg');
var height = oBlock.offsetHeight;
var w = document.getElementById('sub_text')
var hg = height / 2;
var hg2 = "padding-top:"hg"px";
w.style.cssText = hg2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего не получается, потому что `"padding-top:"hg"px"` - синтаксически неправильно. То есть весь блок кода вообще не выполняется из-за ошибки парсера.

```
w.style.paddingTop = (height / 2) + "px";
```